# puppetlabs/apache: Invalid relationship: File[/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf]

Tags: apache, puppetlabs-apache

I just pulled the puppetlabs-apache git repository since a few months and when I run puppet I get the message:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid relationship: File[/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf] { require => File[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf] }, because File[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf] doesn't seem to be in the catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

This is my site manifests file:

```
class { 'apache':
  mpm_module => 'prefork',
}
include apache::mod::php

class { 'postgresql::server': }
class { 'zabbix':
  zabbix_url       => 'zabbix.dj-wasabi.nl',
  manage_resources => true,
}
```

This always worked before, but fails every time know. It doesn't matter which puppet version (3 or 4) or Linux OS (Centos, Ubuntu or Debian).

Am I missing something?

Kind regards,
Werner

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Puppetlabs is tracking this issue here:
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-2850